# Why eloquent separates queries in eager loading?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

For example I have two queries:

```
return $this->model->where('closed_at', null)
            ->whereHas('users', function ($query) {
                $query->where('id', '=', auth()->user()->id);
            })         
            ->with(['product:id,title', 'in_works' => function ($query) {
                $query->where('user_id', '=', auth()->user()->id);
            }])
           ->get();
```

its work good and return 1 query with join(eager loading):

```
select * from `order` where `closed_at` is null and exists (select * from `user` inner join `user_order` on `user`.`id` = `user_order`.`user_id` where `order`.`id` = `user_order`.`order_id` and `id` = ?)
```

**but** similar query

```
return $this->model->where('closed_at', null)
            ->with(['product:id,title', 'in_works' => function ($query) {
                $query->where('closed_at', '=', null);
            }])->get();
```

return 3 queries, why?

```
select * from `order` where `closed_at` is null
select `id`, `title` from `product` where `product`.`id` in (1, 2)
select * from `in_work` where `in_work`.`order_id` in (1, 2) and `closed_at` is null
```

Comment: Can you show the generated query for the first example? I find it hard to believe that one runs a single query; each relationship (array value in `with()`) should be another query.

Comment: Thanks, but don't post code in the comments. You have the ability to edit your question; please do so. Anyway, I don't see where `product` and `in_works` is being loaded; seems to be missing, and I'm not sure why. Sidenote: `product` is a bad table name; should be `products`

Comment: @AndreyShchedrin how do you get this query, by `->toSql()`?

Comment: I used dd(DB::getQueryLog());

Comment: ^ That's a good point; one of those is `toSql()`, the other looks like the query log. Use the same method for testing; `toSql()` doesn't show related queries, but `DB::queryLog()` (or whatever the method is) will show all executed queries.

Comment: i use similar debug features, in first case it return 1 query, in second 3 queries, why?

Comment: The first query you posted there is parameterized (shows `?` instead of `1`) and is the result of `->toSql()`, and doesn't include the queries call with `with()`. The 2nd set of 3 queries is the result of `DB::getQueryLog();`, which shows the actual query being run, including params instead of `?`, and the additional queries run with `with()`. You say you're using the same debug method, but you have 2 different results from two different methods... Anyway, it's been explained what's happening and why.

Comment: first case also result of DB::getQueryLog();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each relationship added to a model via eager loading (i.e. using `with`) is queried via an additional query.

Here's what you have:

1. Model query

```
select * from `order` where `closed_at` is null -- Model
```

2. with `product:id,title` query

```
select `id`, `title` from `product` where `product`.`id` in (1, 2)
```

3. with `in_works` query

```
select * from `in_work` where `in_work`.`order_id` in (1, 2) and `closed_at` is null
```

Note that in cases (2) and (3) `(1,2)` corresponds to the identifiers of `order` that were obtained from the first query.

`whereHas` will further refine the original model query and therefore affect the total results returned. In your case the following is the result of the `whereHas('users',...)` query:

```
select * from `order` where `closed_at` is null and exists (select * from `user` inner join `user_order` on `user`.`id` = `user_order`.`user_id` where `order`.`id` = `user_order`.`order_id` and `id` = ?)
```

When a model query does not actually yield any results then no relationship queries are actually performed which is what is happening in this case.